# What happened to Black Widow, and what did it have to do with Hawkeye?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow

In a post-credit scene in the new MCU film, [*Black Widow* (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3480822/), someone tells Yelena that Black Widow was killed by Hawkeye.  Can someone explain this to me?  I don't recall anything like this happening in any MCU film.  Was this a "spoiler" for a future film?  I apologize, I'm not very knowledgeable of the comics.

Comment: You have a couple of great answers here and I won't make a third just to add that this post-credit scene is (I believe) a teaser for the _Hawkeye_ miniseries on Disney+ where this "conflict" is resolved.

Answer (score 8):

This is a reference to what happens to Nat in *Avengers: Endgame*. The reason Nat died is because she was sacrificed by Clint to get the Soul Stone. Of course it isn't as black and white as that and we, the audience, know exactly what happens but:

1. It isn't clear how well known the events of Vormir are known to others even though Valentina (the woman who was talking to Yelena) probably knows more than most.
2. What Valentina's motivations are. She certainly doesn't seem to be a 100% good guy and so she may be twisting the truth for her own gain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is spoilers for Endgame (and Infinity War, somewhat).

> Hawkeye and Black Widow travel to Vormir to get the soul stone, and Red Skull tells them "The Stone demands a sacrifice. In order to take it, you must leave behind that which you love." Hawkeye and Black Widow realize that one of them has to be sacrificed so that the other one can get the stone. They each try to sacrifice themselves, while trying to keep the other from doing so. Black Widow succeeds in keeping Hawkeye from sacrificing himself and throws herself off the cliff, allowing Hawkeye to get the stone.
> It's a bit inaccurate to say that Hawkeye killed Black Widow; he did everything he could to keep her from dying. I guess in some sense his failure to prevent Black Widow from sacrificing herself caused her death, but it's rather unfair to characterize that as him "killing" her. Of course, the only people who witnesses the events were Black Widow, Hawkeye, and Red Skull, and one of them is dead and one of them presumably is still stuck on Vormir, so it's not clear how this information got to Yelena. Perhaps Hawkeye told someone what happened and the information, intentionally or not, got mangled on its way to Yelena (perhaps someone has some motive for having Yelena blame Hawkeye?). Perhaps Hawkeye feels survivor guilt and is telling people himself that he was responsible for her death. Perhaps people found out that he went to Vormir with Black Widow and came back alone and made inferences.

Comment: So this is pretty much what's on TheLethalCarrot's answer, but your entire answer is a spoiler tag...

Comment: @Luciano TheLethalCarrot's answer is inaccurate, as Clint did not sacrifice Natasha.

Comment: @Acccumulation Technically he did and he didn't depending on your point of view. For the purpose of the answer though I don't think it's relevant as we're going off of at least third part information here.